# JQuery Accordion Bigger Icons

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm trying to put an icon bigger than the default 16x16 in the accordion header.  I do this by using the following code:

```
.ui-accordion-header.user .ui-icon {
background: url(../../Content/Images/User.gif);
height: 32px;
width: 32px;
```

}

The problem is the bottom of the icon is cut off and is not centered.  Is there something I'm missing or do I need to go in and override some of the CSS defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header { height: 32px /* or more */; }
.ui-accordion-icons .ui-accordion-header a { padding-left: 32px /* or more */; }
```

as well. The icon is set to `position: absolute` which is why the header doesn't expand to fit the icon.

It is fairly easy to do a home-brew accordion but you would be spurning ARIA support, any keyboard accessibility built into the widget, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my own personal experience, customizing the jQuery components is only worth-while if you are using a suite of them and are trying to maintain a consistent look & feel.

If you are just looking to create an accordion, you can certainly code one yourself that's equally as good as theirs. [Here is one I whipped up a little while ago](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/Mq8f4/) with larger icons. I'm sure it can be optimized and improved. Feel free to use/modify it as you need to.